# Left outer join not fetching all records of left table

Tags: hive

I have scenario here, have 2 tables say A and B.
A table has `emp_id` and `date` and B table has 2 dates `ppl_d`, `expr_d` and `emp_id`

When did the left join in hive like,

```
select A.emp_id
from A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
where A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d
```

I see there is one employee in Table A and not in B, and when I do `LEFT JOIN` the particular `emp_id` has to come but it is not coming because in the where condition there is `NULL` for both `appl_id` and expr id... 
How can I handle NULL's so that the particular `emp_id` should come into my result. I tried coalesce function also, but no luck... tried putting default value but still no luck... 
Let me know for any details. Thanks in advance... and these dates are in string format..

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. If you don't want the WHERE to apply, you should modify it to be the conditions you actually want. For example, add clauses like `OR B.appl_d IS NULL`.

Comment: I need Where clause to be applied with handling NULL's to get missing emp_id record. How can I modify this

Comment: select A.emp_id
from A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
where A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d or b.appl_d is null or b.expr_d is null --- like this???

Comment: Yes, that sort of thing. To avoid ambiguity, you should probably wrap your and/or with `()` to guarantee they are grouped correctly. For example: `(C between X and Y) or W or Z`

Comment: Yeah, I did that... and you know, I am getting what I need :)... Thank you so much for the help...  How mark your comment as correct??

Comment: Goodo! You can upvote the comment if you feel like it. Or just write up your own answer.

Comment: One last question on this thread, if I want to join one more table... I tried...select A.emp_id
from A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
where A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d or B.appl_d is null or B.expr_d is null LEFT OUTER JOIN C on a.emp_id=c.emp_id where a.date between c.del_d and c.fin_d or del_d is null or fin_d is null I am getting like "missing EOF at 'LEFT' near 'NULL'"

Comment: you can't add join after where. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-SelectSyntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `between` condition does not allow nulls add left join is transformed to inner. Add `OR b.emp_id is NULL` (join key) this will allow not joined records, no need to add the same conditions for all columns used in the `between`.

```
    select *
    from A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
    LEFT JOIN C on a.emp_id=c.emp_id 
    where ((A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d) OR b.emp_id is NULL)
          and
          ((a.date between c.del_d and c.fin_d) OR c.emp_id is NULL)
```

And this is a test:

```
with 
A as
(    
     select stack(3,100,'2019-01-13',
                    200,'2019-01-13',
                    300,'2019-01-13'
                 ) as (emp_id, date)
 ),

 B as (
 select stack(1,100,'2019-12-30','3000-01-01') as (emp_id, appl_d, expr_d)
 ),

 C as
 (
 select stack(1,100,'2015-06-07', '9999-12-31') as (emp_id, del_d, fin_d)
 )

 select A.*
   from A 
        LEFT JOIN B ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
        LEFT JOIN C on a.emp_id=c.emp_id 
   where ((A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d) OR b.appl_d is NULL) 
          and
         ((a.date between c.del_d and c.fin_d) OR c.emp_id is NULL)
```

Result:

```
OK
200     2019-01-13
300     2019-01-13
Time taken: 84.475 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Obviously this approach does not work. emp_id=100 should be in the dataset returned.

And the question is interesting, I will continue investigating a bit later. You guys can use my test to find the working solution.

Comment: I have written the query bit differently as per data, and its fetching what I need. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I have written the query like select *
from
(
    select A.col0 
    from A 
    LEFT JOIN B 
    ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
    where (A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d) 
    OR B.appl_d is NULL
    OR B.expr_d is NULL  -- to allow nulls (not joined records)
) a 
LEFT JOIN C K
on a.emp_id=K.emp_id
LEFT JOIN D L
on a.emp_id=L.emp_id
Where a.date between C.del_d and C.fin_d
AND a.date between D.allo_d and D.akp_d but I am sure will miss some records... because of where condition having between dates clause... How to rewrite the query, Kindly help..

Comment: Use the same method:    ` LEFT JOIN C K on a.emp_id=K.emp_id 
 LEFT JOIN D L on a.emp_id=L.emp_id 
 Where ((a.date between C.del_d and C.fin_d) OR K.emp_id is null)
      AND 
   ((a.date between D.allo_d and D.akp_d) OR L.emp_id  is null)`

Comment: No, still missing the record, the particular employee is present in all table a, K as well as L... may I know what is  emp_id is NULL do ?? and I am including all NULLs in C and D temp tables...

Comment: @Ma28 If record was not joined with the right table, then condition OR  emp_id (from right table) is null allows such records (not joined)

Comment: @Ma28 simplified query for two tables

Comment: but, as i mentioned in temp table itself am getting between dates condition all having nulls so that employee to come also... i believe we need to write this query bit differently... any other thoughts... ?? please guide

Comment: @Ma28  Have you some representative data example? Do not quite understand

Comment: Consider my above query itself and Let assume there is one employee id 100, is there in table A and also in B and has appl_d and expr_d as 2019-12-30 and 3000-01-01 and a.date is 2019-01-13, then should come in first subquery a,
also, and is coming also available in C and also in D and that employee C.del_d and C.fin_d are 2015-06-07 and 9999-12-31  and employee D.allo_d and D.akp_d dates are 2018-09-23 & 3000-01-01

Let assume A.date is 2019-01-13... Hope I am clear with data...

Comment: @Ma28 I prepared some small script for checking this. I have no the solution yet, but I will publish my test script, maybe someone else also will help w this.

Comment: no need dig in further, think I am getting what I suppose to get... Your answer  select *
    from A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
    LEFT JOIN C on a.emp_id=c.emp_id 
    where ((A.date between B.appl_d and B.expr_d) OR b.emp_id is NULL)
          and
          ((a.date between c.del_d and c.fin_d) OR c.emp_id is NULL) gives me what I need and the missing emp_id not supposed come which fine and its a data issue... Thanks for supporting through out this.. Very much appreciated....:) will get back if anything arises ....:)